# What is the correct way to bind events in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, events, bind

For example in php I have a list of clients:

```
foreach($clients as $client)
    echo '<li id="client_'.$client->id.'">' . $client->name . '</li>';
```

What is the correct way to bind a click event to each list item w/o using

```
onclick="my_function(the_elements_id)"
```

right in the list item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you have a ul with id="client_list"

```
$("#client_list li").click(function()
{
    var myid = $(this).attr("id"); // the clicked on items id
    // do your thing here.

}):
```

Comment: `$(this).attr("id")` is not as efficient as `this.id`.  Every HTML object will have an `id` attribute; you don't need jQuery to soften this up for you.

Answer (score 4):

And very cool **"live"** way of binding for all current and future matched elements. This comes in handy if you use Ajax, and have to re-bind event to let's say image that you fetch via ajax.

More info @ http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn

```
$("p").live("click", function(){
  alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  New to jQuery and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes live is great if there's any chance of the markup being changed on the fly. It's an implementation of delegation.

Comment: Used it today.  Very useful.  Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use .bind

E.g.

```
$('#item').bind("click", function() { do something; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("li).click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        your_function(id); //The function you want to run with the object's ID as a parameter.
    });

});
```